# ¿Por qué "a la bartola" es "descuidando o abandonando el trabajo u otra actividad"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones

El Diccionario de la Lengua recoge:

> [**bartola**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=59dvWXg)
>
> De *Bartolo*, acort. de *Bartolomé*; cf. *bartolear*.
>
> a la bartola
>
> 1. loc. adv. coloq. Descuidando o abandonando el trabajo u otra actividad. *Echarse, tumbarse a la bartola.*
> 2. loc. adv. coloq. Despreocupándose, quedando libre de toda inquietud o preocupación.

¿Como se asoció ese nombre a esa actitud despreocupada / descuidada?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Tu apodo me recuerda [una pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18036/12637) que ya hicimos por aquí al respecto...

Comment: En [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16592/12637) a otra pregunta se menciona de pasadas el origen de la expresión, aunque no veo mal que se haga una pregunta aparte para profundizar un poco más en su origen y significado.

Answer (score 2):

Como de costumbre, el blog de *[El listo que todo lo sabe](http://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/de-donde-viene-la-expresion-tirarse-a-la-bartola/)* nos aclara el origen de la expresión:

> la procedencia de la expresión tendría lugar en la celebración de **San Bartolomé**, que se celebra el 24 de agosto. Para esa fecha las cosechas terminaban y **comenzaba un periodo de descanso y festejos** hasta que, unos días después, diese comienzo la vendimia.

Answer (score 1):

Veo la palabra *bartola* haciendo referencia a la "panza" en una [carta de 1787](https://books.google.cl/books?id=Lz5OAAAAYAAJ&q=bartola):

> Quando un hombre era soldado con ensaladas de berros se llenaba la bartola.

Y en un [texto de 1776](https://books.google.cl/books?id=NvsJkvJyAmwC&q=bartola) la frase *a la Bartola* significa "tendido de espaldas" (o sea, con la panza hacia arriba):

> ...yo también de aquí a un rato me ire a tender a la Bartola en mi Cama.

El DRAE ya no recoge esta acepción de "vientre" para *bartola*. Según Corominas, ése sería el origen de la expresión *a la bartola* ("perezosamente, despreocupadamente"), que se habría referido a la posición supina. Según este investigador

> Procede por antonomasia de Bartolo, forma abreviada de Bartolomé empleada a menudo como nombre de personajes desocupados o perezosos.

Sin embargo, no he podido encontrar ninguna referencia a algún Bartolomé perezoso en cuentos tradicionales o leyendas.

En [este hilo](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=42049) del foro del español del Centro Virtual Cervantes se menciona la teoría de Corominas y se agrega esta otra:

> Otros autores —quizá con más fundamento— sostienen que la expresión «a la bartola» fue acuñada por los humanistas del siglo XV (más precisamente, por los integrantes del llamado humanismo jurídico). Tiene un sentido netamente peyorativo. Con la misma se hacía referencia al método de trabajo empleado por la escuela jurídica llamada de los postglosadores, cuyo máximo exponente fue Bártolo de Sassoferrato (1314-1357).

En este caso, los seguidores de Bártolo (de quien también deriva la palabra "bártulos") habrían trabajado en forma despreocupada y poco metódica.

Siguiendo otros enlaces derivados del mismo hilo, se ve que no hay acuerdo sobre el origen, y que generalmente se prefiere el indicado en la respuesta de @Diego.